# Lost Sim graphic in The Sims 3

Tags: the-sims-3

My game is playing normally, but today when I play it, all sims (expect my Sim) can't be displayed, and I can't interact with them. My Sim can still interact with them automically. All objects act like there are other sims there (for example, the chairs are moving, fridge is openned, ... ). Sometimes I meet a Sim that has the body, but without the head!

Here is my computer hardwares (all drivers are updated): CPU Core i5, ATI Radeon 5700, 4GB RAM, Windows 7 Pro 64bit. TS3 has World Adventure and Ambitions expansion pack.

Has anybody met this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Create a backup of your saved games and then re-install the game and re apply your saves, it's most likely a corruption of files.